# datetime: subtracting date from itself yields 3288 days

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

I have a bunch of dates in a pandas dataframe, mostly observed for July of each year, of type `datetime64[ns]`.

```
In [126]:

e6.To.head()
Out[122]:
14   1991-07-01
15   1992-07-01
16   1993-07-01
17   1994-07-01
18   1995-07-01
Name: To, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I ultimately want to store in a separate variable the rolling difference from one row to the next using `shift()`, but I found subtracting dates to produce odd results. Here, I subtract a series of dates from itself (reprinting the first five results. Some of them are, as expected, 0, but others are obviously not.

```
In [127]:

(e6.To-e6.To).head()
Out[127]:
1       0 days
1   -3288 days
1    3288 days
1       0 days
2       0 days
Name: To, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If I take just the top five observations and then subtract, I do not get this result, and get all 0's as expected:

```
In [128]:

e6.To.head()-e6.To.head()
Out[119]:
14   0 days
15   0 days
16   0 days
17   0 days
18   0 days
Name: To, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I can't reproduce it if I 'enter' the data directly, like so:

```
In [128]:

test=pd.DataFrame(data=['1991-07-01','1992-07-01','1993-07-01','1994-07-01','1995-07-01','1996-07-01'],columns=['date'])
test['date']=test['date'].astype('datetime64')
test.date - test.date
Out[128]:
0   0 days
1   0 days
2   0 days
3   0 days
4   0 days
5   0 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What version pandas, numpy are you using?

Comment: That's 9 years and 3 days (or nine years with three leap years), in case it helps.

Comment: pandas: 0.14.1; numpy 1.9.0

Comment: Could you try upgrading, are you able to post any raw input data and code to reproduce this?

Comment: Why is the index 14-18 for 1st and 3rd but 1,1,1,1,2 for the 2nd?  Shouldn't those 3 all have the same index?  Also, I doubt it matters but I would avoid something like 'To' as a column name.  It's not 'in', 'if', or 'for' but I'd avoid prepositions for variable names as a general rule.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer but I need some space to show something.  My guess is that something weird is going on with indexing (I have no idea why, though).  Note my comment about indexing above and also note @ASGM's comment about the difference being very close to 9 years.

I'm using your code to create the sample data above, but adding a few years and sticking to the name of 'e6' for the dataframe and 'To' for the variable in the event that matters (I really doubt it, but you know...)

```
In [10]: e6
Out[10]: 
           To
0  1991-07-01
1  1992-07-01
2  1993-07-01
3  1994-07-01
4  1995-07-01
5  1996-07-01
6  1997-07-01
7  1998-07-01
8  1999-07-01
9  2000-07-01
10 2001-07-01
11 2002-07-01

In [11]: e6.To - e6.To[9]
Out[11]: 
0    -3288 days
1    -2922 days
2    -2557 days
3    -2192 days
4    -1827 days
5    -1461 days
6    -1096 days
7     -731 days
8     -366 days
9        0 days
10     365 days
11     730 days
Name: To, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Ya, I noticed too that the index repeated, so that must be the reason, although not sure just why that comes into play when subtracting a series from itself. I tried some reindexing and it behaved as expected.

Comment: Pandas is automatically doing indexing behind the scenes.  Even if you subtract something from itself, it's really doing ```x.sub(x)``` and there is automatic alignment going on -- in this case pandas doesn't really know that it's the same thing on both sides -- just that one thing is being subtracted from another thing, and not to assume they are already lined up in advance.  All that said, I don't know why pandas auto-alignment wouldn't line things up the way you'd expect.

Comment: I uploaded an example here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/www.urbs.dk/notebooks/DOFe6ParseMigration1990_2014_indexissue.ipynb